# WebView sempre perguntando onde quero abrir a url

Tags: android, webview

O meu Web View toda vez que testo em meu celular esta me perguntando como desejo abrir a url, porem preciso que abra no webview. Bom o código é este :

Activity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class ConectActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conect);

        String url = "http://google.com";
        WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(true);
        wv.loadUrl("https://google.com");


    }
}
```

Activity do layout

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>
```

E no manifest esta :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Alguém por favor saberia como posso resolver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de chamar o método `loadUrl()` tem de indicar à webView qual o cliente a utilizar:

```
String url = "http://google.com";
WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setSupportZoom(true);

wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

wv.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, obrigado XD