# Como fazer o webview funcionar, já tentei mas ela não funciona

Tags: android, webview

eu já tentei de tudo mas a minha webview não funciona. me ajudem

o codigo java

public class TelaIrlanda extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_irlanda);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();




   WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
            ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            ws.setSupportZoom(false);

            wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.br");
```

Comment: O que não funciona? Veja se esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94008/2541) resolve.

Comment: O codigo esta correto, mas olha se você colocou permissão de acesso a internet

Comment: Coloquei a permissão no manifest 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.junior.intercambio">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: Entao tenta colocar "wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());" antes do loadUrl

Comment: Ola, voce esta tentando no android 6? se sim é necessario solicitar a permissão em tempo de execução

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-6-marshmallow-runtime-permissions-request-example/

Comment: @JoãoFelipe A permissão `android.permission.INTERNET` não pertence à lista de [permissões perigosas](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups), não sendo por isso necessário a sua solicitação em tempo de execução.